# jQuery<random> attribute on <div>?

Tags: jquery, html

What is this `jQuery111006524838721774548` attribute I am seeing in my `<div>`?
It has a value of `"4"`.
What does the property and the value mean?

```
<div class="myClass" style="display: none;" jQuery111006524838721774548="4"/>
```

Comment: it is a jQuery internal reference key for the cached jQuery object reference